# Expo: run existing EAS dev client

Tags: android, expo

After building a custom Dev Client using EAS (`eas build --profile development --platform android`), I get the following, very useful prompt in the CLI letting me install it directly on a locally running device:

[image]

However, what if I want to use the *same* EAS dev client on *another* machine *without* re-running the entire build? I know I can manually install the build e.g. using the QR code, but I would much prefer to use the CLI so that this setup can be automated.